# Apply with linkedin button

Tags: linkedin-api

(or anyone with knowledge on this subject).

I have been requested to place an "apply with linkedin" button on a clients website, so that job applicants can apply using there linkedin details to make the process a bit easier (please note that this is not for large scale requirement, and is for one company).

Button docs here for ref:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/talent/apply-with-linkedin

I have read the docs and come to the understanding that linkedIn only allows this API feature if:

1. You have a Linkedin enterprise account
2. You have a ATS account

I was hoping to get some clarification on these two points to see if I am correct? Or if there is a way to a normal business account can use this feature?

Thank you for any help you can offer here,

All the best,
Wally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting for anyone who finds this in future -

LinkedIn requires you to have their ATS system to use the apply with LinkedIn button from their API page.... This costs allot of Money (from my POV - but business class is a thing because businesses have allot of money).

This is not explicitly stated on the site, more like:

To use this feature you need ATS
To get ATS you need to speak with sales and pay for it (I ended up on the phone to a sales rep in Irl to find this out.... so pretty good example of where docs could be more explicate rather than implicit).